# Issue while removing directory using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is the test scenario I followed to remove the directory by using batch file.

1. Created one folder under temp directory, **mkdir %temp%\abc**

Copied some good amount of folders and files into the **abc** folder under temp.

1. Copied %temp%\abc folder to some other location as "C:\Program Files (x86)\xyz". Command is

**xcopy /s /q %temp%\abc "%C:\Program Files (x86)\xyz%"**. Successfully copied.

1. Now I thought of remove the temp folder %temp%\abc. Command is

**rmdir /s /q %temp%\abc**

Here the issue am getting is **"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. The batch file cannot be found."**

Can anyone please tell me what could be the reason and what changes should I do to remove the temp directory.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
 The batch file cannot be found.
```

The key is in the second line. You are running the batch file from inside the same folder you are trying to remove. The `rmdir` command worked and removed everything it could, including your batch file that now can not continue execution as it does not exist.

Place batch file in another folder and ensure you do not call the `rmdir` from a path under the starting delete point.